# extend unallocated disk to an existing lvm

Tags: ubuntu, lvm

im using vmware on my ubuntu server, initial setup was 10GB disk utilization, increased it to 15GB using `lvextend` and added another 5GB for a total of 20GB.

below displays my `fdisk -l`

```
Disk /dev/sda: 21.5 GB, 21474836480 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 2610 cylinders, total 41943040 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x0002948a

   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sda1   *        2048      499711      248832   83  Linux
/dev/sda2          501758    20969471    10233857    5  Extended
/dev/sda3          499712      501757        1023   83  Linux
/dev/sda4        20969472    31457279     5243904   8e  Linux LVM
/dev/sda5          501760    20969471    10233856   8e  Linux LVM
```

**/dev/sda4** is actually an extension of my **/dev/sda5**

```
root@media:~# pvscan
  PV /dev/sda5   VG media   lvm2 [9.76 GiB / 0    free]
  PV /dev/sda4   VG media   lvm2 [5.00 GiB / 0    free]
  Total: 2 [14.76 GiB] / in use: 2 [14.76 GiB] / in no VG: 0 [0   ]
```

i still have unallocated disk somewhere in my **/dev/sda** as stated above and i want to use it.

but when i create a new partition in my `fdisk /dev/sda` to get the additional 5GB, i get this `1023` blocks instead.

```
Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sda3          499712      501757        1023   83  Linux
```

by ignoring above, and creating another partition on my **/dev/sda**
this shows..

```
All primary partitions are in use
Adding logical partition 6
No free sectors available
```

i cant seem to create another partition without this

`/dev/sda3          499712      501757        1023   83  Linux`

happening. can someone assist what im doing wrong?

basically, what i had in mind is to gradually increase the partition size of my server.
from 10 + 5 + 5 + so on...

windows was able to extend unallocated space without any problems and rebooting. im very new to linux and i hope someone would help me understand whats happening in my issue.

```
root@media:~# pvs
  PV         VG    Fmt  Attr PSize PFree
  /dev/sda4  media lvm2 a-   5.00g    0
  /dev/sda5  media lvm2 a-   9.76g    0

root@media:~# lvs
  LV     VG    Attr   LSize  Origin Snap%  Move Log Copy%  Convert
  root   media -wi-ao 13.76g
  swap_1 media -wi-ao  1.00g

root@media:~# vgs
  VG    #PV #LV #SN Attr   VSize  VFree
  media   2   2   0 wz--n- 14.76g    0
```

Comment: Please add the output of `pvs`, `vgs` and `lvs`

Comment: added info requested..

Answer (score 1):

Why not make your life easier and use LVM for the extension? 
If I was on your place, I would backup the data from the server (20 GB are not much at all), then:

```
umount <respective mount point>
lvremove media
vgremove media
pvremove /dev/sda4
pvremove /dev/sda5
```

Partition `/dev/sda`:

```
    fdisk /dev/sda
    p -> print 
    d 5 -> delete /dev/sda5
    d 4 -> delete /dev/sda4
    d 3 -> delete /dev/sda3
    d 2 -> delete /dev/sda2
    p -> print to confirm your changes
    n -> create new partition, take the defaults to acquire the max disk space possible for it, choose primary partition (LVM will manage it afterwards)
    t -> change the type of the partition to LVM
    w
```

As `/dev/sda1` is in use the changes will be visible after reboot. Then `fdisk -l /dev/sda` will output:

```
Disk /dev/sda: 21.5 GB, 21474836480 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 2610 cylinders, total 41943040 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x0002948a

   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sda1   *        2048      499711      248832   83  Linux
/dev/sda2          499712    20969471    10233857   8e  Linux LVM
```

Add `/dev/sda2` to LVM, create volume group and partition:

```
pvcreate /dev/sda2
vgcreate media /dev/sda2
lvcreate --size 14G --name root media
lvcreate --size 1G --name swap_1 media (in my experience `--extents` is more precise than `--size`. Verify by `vgdisplay` there are no Free Extents)
Create filesystems and enable swap for the newly created logical volumes.
```

Advantage of this setup: flexibility. The logical volume size may be smaller than the volume group, hence the filesystem will be smaller too. Then to increase the size, use `lvextend` and increase the filesystem afterwards.

Disadvantage: have to delete all partitions, backup and restore the data.